# Can I link texts in latex so that they are changed together?

Tags: links, text

I want to link between words in latex so that I can change all words linked to the original word along with the original one.

Here is example.

I made a sample **A1**. A1 is good. A1 is beautiful.

Now when I change the bold one to B1, then all the A1 change to B1.

I made a sample **B1**. B1 is good. B1 is beautiful.

I hope I explained clearly.

Thank you!

Comment: You can make a \newcommand: `\newcommand{\Word}{A1}`  In you text you will use  ̀\Word` each time you will write A1. You can later change the definition of the command.

Comment: @omisson, Thank you very much!. One more thing, is there any way to use numbers in {\Word}?

Comment: It's not possible to have a command name with numbers, but you could use roman numbers…

Comment: After some reading, it seems possible to use numbers in commands but quite complicated and not recommended, as explained here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-linmacnames.html. I've written an answere, please accept it if you problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment, you could use a simple command:

```
\newcommand\Wi{A1}
```

I made a sample \Wi. \Wi is good. \Wi is beautiful.

And then change youre \Wi command definition or redefine it with:

```
\renewcommand\Wi{B2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\newcommand{\mysample}[1]{I made a sample \textbf{#1}. {#1} is good. {#1} is beautiful.}

\mysample{A1}

\mysample{B1}
```